# If condition not working in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three buttons, + value -. in this when i click + button value will increase and - value will be decrease .. i have wote the code in jSFIDLLE. it working.

And the value should not be minus. so i added one if condition. then my code is not working.

**html-**

```
<input type="Button" id='AddButton' value="+" />
<input type="Button" id='BoqTextBox' value="0" />
<input type="Button" id='MinusButton' value="-" />
```

**javascript -**

```
$('#AddButton').on('click', function () {
    var input = $('#BoqTextBox');
    input.val(parseFloat(input.val(), 10) + 1);
})
$('#MinusButton').on('click', function () {    
  var input = $('#BoqTextBox');
    if(input>0)
    { input.val(parseFloat(input.val(), 10) - 1);}
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sagotharan/J4Jxa/1/

Comment: `input` is an object, a jQuery object. What makes you think it will be greater than 0?

Comment: use `.val()` property of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if(input.val()>0)` instead of `if(input>0)`

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a HTML element with 0. You need to compare its value with 0

Try

```
if (input.val() > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
if(input.val() > 0)
```

As

```
if(input > 0)
```

Means that you are trying to see if the object, not it's value is bigger than 0, which is not the case as it is an element

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare `input` with 0. You should instead compare the *value* of `input` with 0.

Replace

```
if (input > 0)
```

with

```
if (parseInt(input.val()) > 0)
```

Comment: is parseInt need to add,. input.val() gives output, and parseInt(input.val() also. what is the use of parseInt?

Comment: The difference is the type of the result: `input.val()` equals the *string* `"1"` whereas `parseInt(input.val())` equals the *number* `1`. It works if you omit to call `parseInt()` because javascript is smart : when it compares the string `"1"` and the integer `0`, it understands that the string is, in fact, an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(input.val() > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
$('#AddButton').on('click', function () {
    var input = $('#BoqTextBox');
    input.val(parseFloat(input.val(), 10) + 1);
})
$('#MinusButton').on('click', function () {    
  var input = $('#BoqTextBox');
    if(input.val()>0)
    { input.val(parseFloat(input.val(), 10) - 1);}
})
```